# During http live streaming audio continues but video cuts out after 30 seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, http-live-streaming

I have edited my videos in final cut pro and used their export to http live streaming, which includes an audio, cell low and hi video, wifi low and hi, .m3u8 and index files. I have put all the files onto my web server and am using this to call the videos

```
-(IBAction)introVideo:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"intro button pressed");
    NSString *url = @"http://www.andalee.com/iPhoneVideos/intro/Intro.m3u8";
    MPMoviePlayerViewController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}
```

(Side note: how should this be released?)

Here is the Index.m3u8

```
    #EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=225416,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.42e015"
    Intro%20-%20Cellular%20Low.segments/prog_index.m3u8
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=480386,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.42e015"
    Intro%20-%20Cellular%20High.segments/prog_index.m3u8
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=751434,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.42e01e"
    Intro%20-%20Wi-Fi%20Low.segments/prog_index.m3u8
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1250210,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d401e"
    Intro%20-%20Wi-Fi%20High.segments/prog_index.m3u8
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2545049,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d401e"
    Intro%20-%20Broadband%20Low.segments/prog_index.m3u8
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=5056100,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d401f"
    Intro%20-%20Broadband%20High.segments/prog_index.m3u8
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=33290,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
    Intro%20-%20Audio%20for%20HTTP%20Live%20Streaming.segments/prog_index.m3u8
```

When I test my app I initially get video and sound, but after 30 seconds I lose video while the audio continues to play. Any ideas what would be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the file which is used next after the intro has wrong codec or the path is not right. Make sure all of the paths in `Intro.m3u8` are correct and reachable from outside.

Comment: What you are saying completely makes sense, but it was happening with all the videos on my app. they were all stopping at the 30 second mark. The weird thing is that when I ran it just know they all worked perfectly? Does this make any sense to you? And thank you for the quick and helpful replies.

Comment: Could you post your `Intro.m3u8` file?

Answer (score 3):

This could simply be caused by a low bandwidth condition, which will trigger a bitrate change (in this case to the audio only version). If you try it in the emulator with a local server it might work correctly.